Why is my encoder showing abnormal spikes on the oscilloscope readings? Any suggestions on what might be causing it?
So to summarize, I have these winch drives that I've put together. One of them went berserk during testing and now I'm diagnosing the problem. I have attached an oscilloscope to where the KEB servo motor's (incremental encoder) cable is connected to my Stagehand v6 control card via contactor block (see below for pictures.) The signals I get from the channels (A+,A-,B+,B-) have this constant spike/ring during each duty cycle period. I compared it to the working winch drive we have and there's a clear difference in signal. Can a signal or RF specialist give me suggestions to what could be causing this?
Oscilloscope set up:

Bad Winch Signal:

Good Winch Signal:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would suspect ground connections. I presume the cable between the encoder has "ground" or "common" conductor(s). I would check to see if they are intact and connected at both ends.

There is a power switching device close by, which interferes here. But the receiver circuit of this encoder signal should be able to deal with this kind of common mode noise, at least if it is a true differential receiver.
You can put a snap on ferrite around the cable to dampen this noise, but the problem may be somewhere else. I would verify, that no wires are interchanged and the rotation direction is correct.
If nothing helps, move the whole connection unit away from the noise source to another location.

Various theories/qualified guessing:
It kind of looks like noise from mains since it isn't in sync with the PWM signal. You live in North America 60Hz? A crappy power supply could be the culprit.
Other than that, the installation seems to be on the "rat nest" side of things, so the first thing to do would be to let a professional tidy up the wiring. Neat wiring is not just for looks but also for EMC.
Once that is done you can start examining the motor drives (I'm assuming an electrical winch) and their ground. If someone just grounded that down at an arbitrary place then ground noise is likely.
The spikes could potentially also be EMF from the motors (but then they ought to come at the edges, each time it gets shut on/off) in which case some freewheel diodes will improve the situation, but to know where to place those, you need dig deeper into the design.
Make sure the shield is only grounded at one end and ideally to chassis (DIN rail), not to signal ground. The terminal should one of those that connects to the DIN rail, I can't tell from the picture.
